# Rails if current_page? on dynamically added elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having trouble with if current_page? in a partial.

**Section.html.erb**

```
<div class="list" %>">
    <%= render partial: 'items/item', collection: section.items, :as => :item %>    
</div>
```

**_item.html.erb**

```
<% if current_page?(edit_polymorphic_path(@modulable)) %>

    <span class="action">
        <%= link_to %>
        <%= link_to %>
    </span>

<% end %>
```

The code works fine on a new page load and upon refreshing the page, but doesn't work on a dynamically added element with ajax.

Does this method work with Ajax? Am I doing something wrong? Or do I have to use another method?

Comment: You need to change it by javascript, probably in your ajax, check if response is successful and change the current page link

Comment: It's not rendering at all though, how do I pass the current_page via ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a different method. Instead of having the partial **ask** which page it's in, I passed a local variable to **tell** it what to do instead.

**Section.html.erb**

```
<div class="list" %>">
    <%= render partial: 'items/item', collection: section.items, :as => :item, local: { edit: true } %>    
</div>
```

**_item.html.erb**

```
<% if defined?(edit) && edit %> 
    <span class="action">
        <%= link_to %>
        <%= link_to %>
    </span>
<% end %>
```

And I made sure I passed in the local variable to the new element in update.js.erb

**items/update.js.erb**

```
$('.list').append(
    '<%= j (render partial: 'items/item', locals: { item: @item, edit: true }) %>'
    );
```

It works, and is more explicit.